# Python difference between reading int file and str file

Tags: python, return

What is the difference between opening and returning a file that contains only string and opening and returning file that contain int. For my code for reading str is

```
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()
```

Just want to know what is the difference between reading strings and reading a list of int like [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] and returning it [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Comment: Please elaborate your problem

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file with `open(file_name, 'r')` is always going to give you strings. If you know for a fact the data is numeric. You can do:

```
result = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        result.append([int(word) for word in line.split()])
    return result
```

If you know some of the data could by integers, and some could be strings. Then you can try to convert:

```
result = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        clean_line = []
        for word in line.split():
            try:
                clean_line.append(int(word))
            except: 
                clean_line.append(word)
        result.append(clean_line)
return result
```